# How do I change the Ruby version Textmate uses?

Tags: ruby, macos, textmate

EDIT: I found a solution for this, you can read it in my answer bellow.

I am using Textmate on Snow Leopard, and have installed ruby 1.9. The problem is that for some reason Textmate uses Ruby 1.8.2

But when I use IRB, or run ruby scripts for the shell, the proper version of Ruby (1.9) is used.

How can I configure Textmate so it uses 1.9.2?

I've been googling and apparently you have to use the T_RUBY variable and textmate, and set some environment variable in OSX, but so far none of the methods I've found works for me.

Could someone give a step by step solution to this problem?

Update: I already tried adding the ruby binary path to TM_RUBY in textmate, and I get this error:

```
> Can't find
> “/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> ” on PATH. Theme: The current PATH is:
> /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin Please
> add the directory containing
> “/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> ” to PATH in TextMate's Shell
> Variables preferences.
```

Comment: It can help to **Execute Line (^R)** in a new TextMate document: `type -a ruby && echo "TM_RUBY = $TM_RUBY" && echo "PATH = $PATH"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the path that *which ruby* gave me didnt work. After googling for a while, I found a solution that worked, using the auto-ruby path of rvm as the TM_RUBY variable. 
The path is:
/Users/0al0/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
This only applies if you are using rvm, of course.

Answer (score 31):

If you use RVM, maybe you can try to type:

```
> which rvm-auto-ruby
/Users/eddie/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
```

and set this path as a shell variable named "TM_RUBY" in your textmate perferences like my screenshot

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6931090/downloads/textmate-preferences.png

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I do use RVM, and  will try this when I get home

Comment: Newcomers should not that variables are now set under the "Variables" menu rather than the Advanced > Shell Variables menu.

Answer (score 8):

Under preferences / advanced / shell variables, add a new variable called `TM_RUBY`. And enter the absolute path of your ruby binary.

You can get the latter by opening a terminal and typing:

```
which ruby
```

Comment: That didnt work... I get the following error (see next comment)

Comment: Can't find “/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby ” on PATH.

Theme:  
The current PATH is:

/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
Please add the directory containing “/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.

Comment: @0al0 That is unreadable as a comment. Please edit your original question with details about what you have tried, when steps you perform to test, and the errors you get.

Comment: I did all of this, and now Textmate says: Can't find “/Users/Oscar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby ” on PATH. Please add the directory containing “/Users/Oscar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is actually very easy, no special install procedures are needed. As mentioned on the [TextMate blog](http://blog.macromates.com/2014/defining-a-path/) all you need to do is tell text mate your path variable. TextMate does not load this information by default. In Preferences, go to the *Variables* tab add a variable `PATH` (if it does not already exist) with the value, `$PATH:/usr/local/bin`. This tells TextMate to copy the system PATH. The system's ruby is in `/usr/bin/ruby` which is included in OSX default PATH. If you install a custom version of ruby then also append that path, for example here I have appended `/usr/local/bin` (don't forget the colon).

[image: Updating the PATH variable in TextMate2 preference pane]

Answer (score 3):

If you use `which ruby` and TextMate says `exec: rbenv: not found`, you need to type this instead: `rbenv which ruby`.  Use that path in `TM_RUBY`.

Comment: If you always want to use the current rbenv version, I think you should set `TM_RUBY` = `/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby`.

Comment: Or maybe you can just append `/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims` to TextMate's `PATH`.